Windows 2022 switch embedded teaming failed VM network fail-over test
hyper-v host server connect to L2 2EA TOR and TOR connect on L3 switch.
and TOR switch has no option like below image.

and i connect hyper-v 2022 server on tor switch.
I made switch embedded teaming on windows 2022 hyper-v using below command.
New-VMSwitch -Name "Service_switch" -NetAdapterName "Service01","Service02" -AllowManagementOS $true
after I made windows 2022 vm on that hyper-v host server and assign SET switch on vm.
and I put ip on windows 2022 vm. and ping to vm ip on my local computer.
next, I disabled Service01 or Service02 on hyper-v host.
when disable hyper-v host nic windows 2022 vm ping failed max 120sec(windows arp reflash time)
I checked Arp table cisco L3.
VM ARP move to other switch after 1 ~ 120sec
how can i reduce fail-over on VM?
